# using "at your convenience" while asking a question?

Tags: formality

I am writing an email for a professor in a university and asking some question about a program. First, I asked the questions and in the ending paragraph I wrote:

> I would be grateful if you answer my questions at your best convenience.

Does it elevate the overall politeness of the mail or it is incorrect?

Comment: I'd leave out "best" as it doesn't add anything and I'd add a comma before "at".

Comment: @KillingTime says that "best" adds nothing: I would say that it is not the most appropriate adjective. My preferred version of your sentence would be : _I would be grateful if you could answer my questions at your earliest convenience._ Unfortunately "convenience", in British English at least, also means "public toilet" and "best convenience" sounds more like "preferred public toilet" than "most convenient opportunity" to British ears.

Comment: @BoldBen 'Convenience' _used_ to be used as a euphemism for a public toilet, but hasn't been seen on street signs for several decades. You'd have to be of a certain generation to make the connection, I think.

Comment: @KateBunting possibly, but I am of that generation...

Answer (score 1):

As in:

> I would be grateful for a reply at your convenience.

**at (one's) convenience**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/convenience) an idiom

> - When one has the time to do something.
> - eg. No rush, you can fill out that paperwork at your convenience.

You have posed the questions in the body of the letter.  No need to re-iterate the request to answer them. And 'best' can be pushy ... use it if you must.